# Angular pushing item in an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

When I need to push a new item in an empty array, I got an error : $scope.array.push is not a function.

But when the array is not empty, the push works perfectly and it correctly updates  my scope.

For information, my array is instanciated like this :

```
$scope.array = [];
```

I tried too :

```
$scope.array = [{}]
```

How can I bypass this problem ? Or what am I doing wrong ?

EDIT :

```
$scope.urgences_hygienes = [];

$scope.save = function () {
    $scope.newDemandeHygiene = {
        id_zone : $scope.demandeHygiene.id_zone,
        commentaire : $scope.demandeHygiene.commentaire,
        date_demande : Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)
    }
    $scope.urgences_hygienes.push( $scope.newDemandeHygiene );
    $scope.reloadTable();
    $modalInstance.close();
}
```

Comment: show the line how are you pushing?

Answer (score 1):

the right syntax is: 
    $scope.myarray.push(someobject)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using `$scope.push(var)` instead of `$scope.array.push(var)`.

Additionally, it's worth note that it's faster to just use `$scope.array[$scope.array.length]=var`

Comment: I ve editted my post, my bad to have forgotten to write $scope.array.push(var) in the error log.

Comment: That second statement is a bit of a sweeping generalisation, it varies significantly cross-browser and often dependent on the array length itself.  In any case it's a micro-optimisation that's not worth asserting if someone hasn't specifically asked about it.  Readability should be the important factor in that decision.

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to push in `$scope` instead of `$scope.array`. Error is like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$scope.array.push({});
```

instead.

Comment: Have a look at this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Azamanaza/TRy6X/5/

Could you post more details on this code? The problem might be else where...

Answer (score 0):

The overall code must be this way.

```
$scope.save = function () {
    $scope.urgences_hygienes = [];

    $scope.newDemandeHygiene = {
        id_zone : $scope.demandeHygiene.id_zone,
        commentaire : $scope.demandeHygiene.commentaire,
        date_demande : Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)
    }
    $scope.urgences_hygienes.push( $scope.newDemandeHygiene );
    $scope.reloadTable();
    $modalInstance.close();
}
```